# Outlets in Static Table View Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift, and I just started learning about UITableViews. I recently found that UITableViews can have dynamic or static cells. I know that if using dynamic cells, you must subclass UITableViewCell to hook up outlets. I was wondering however, how you would hook up outlets if you are using static cells. Is it the same way? Please help.

Comment: Yes its the same way, you need to create the subclass of UITableViewCell and hook up your outlets there. don't forget to add the subclass reference to the cell in UIBuilder

Comment: No, it's not necessary to subclass and go through all of that. Just design your static cells however you want and then add outlets for the various UI controls, just like you would if it was a scene without a table view. See Michael's answer.

Comment: Of coz u can use static cells. But for u absolutly better if u never use it. Try do all things proprely from begining.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean an outlet from, say, a `UITextField` within a static `UITableViewCell` to your view controller's code. You don't need to subclass the cell with static cells - you can just ctrl-drag from the field into your code and hook up an outlet (or action).

You don't *need* to do it that way with dynamic cells either. For simple cases, just put a tag on the field in IB, and then when you have the cell, you can use `cell.viewWithTag()` to find it again.

**However**, you would only want to do this for very simple uses, and it would not be considered best practice. It is much better to go the extra distance and subclass `UITableViewCell` for dynamic tables. A good explanation of the options can be found at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702